# Discord guilds.join resulting in Bad Request

Tags: javascript, oauth, request, discord, content-type

I am trying to add a member to my guild using Node's request module.

The **access token** is retrieved through Discord's OAuth2 system. The token provides **identify** and **guilds.join** permissions.

The **bot token** has been copied directly from Discord's development site. The bot is connected to my application, joined the guild I am working with and has permission for both **manage roles** and **create instant invites**.

Here is my request,

```
    request({
        url: `http://discordapp.com/api/guilds/${guildID}/members/${userID}`,
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bot ${botToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: {
            'access_token': access_token
        }
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        console.log(body);
    });
```

and here is the response

```
    { _misc: [ 'Expected "Content-Type" header to be one of {\'application/json\'}.' ] }
```

I have searched through all related questions on here and cannot find the solution.

Any help would be valued. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. You'll want to take advantage of DiscordJS and use the guild.addMember function rather than building your own request.